# PySpark when-otherwise - Expecting positional argument even when provided

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am getting error when using `when otherwise` in PySpark. Could someone please help -

```
df0 = spark.read.option("header", True).csv("dbfs:/FileStore/tables/camp_day0.csv")
df1 = spark.read.option("header", True).csv("dbfs:/FileStore/tables/camp_day1.csv")

def get_aliased_src_columns(day0_df):
    aliased_src_columns = day0_df.select(*(col(column).alias('d1' + '_' + column) for column in day0_df.columns))
    return aliased_src_columns

new_df0 = get_aliased_src_columns(df0)

def join_df1(new_df0, df1):
    join_df1 = new_df0.join(df1,
                            (new_df0.d1_campaign == df1.campaign) & \
                            (new_df0.d1_agencyid == df1.agencyid) \
                                   , "left") \
                         .select( col("d1_campaign").alias("campaign").cast("string"), \
                                  col("d1_agencyid").alias("agencyid").cast("string"), \
                          (when (((col("new_df0.campaign").isNotNull()) & (col("df1.d1_campaignid").isNotNull()), lit('completed'))) \
                                  .otherwise("new_df0.d1_action_curated").alias("status")))

new_df = join_df1(new_df0, df1)
```

Error is: `TypeError: when() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'`

Can someone please help.

Comment: You are passing a tuple with two items, not to parameters (that is what the `when` function requires). Removing two parenthesis you can solve it: `when((col("new_df0.campaign").isNotNull()) & (col("df1.d1_campaignid").isNotNull()), lit('completed'))`

Comment: sorry it didn't solve the issue. could u pls post the entire code.

Answer (score 0):

The [when](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.when.html) function requires two parameters, but you are passing only one (a tuple with two items).

[image]

This is the code fixed (I just eliminated the tuple by removing the parentheses, so the function receives two parameters, not only one):

```py
def join_df1(new_df0, df1):
    join_df1 = new_df0.join(df1,
                            (new_df0.d1_campaign == df1.campaign) & \
                            (new_df0.d1_agencyid == df1.agencyid) \
                                   , "left") \
                         .select( col("d1_campaign").alias("campaign").cast("string"), \
                                  col("d1_agencyid").alias("agencyid").cast("string"), \
                          (when((col("new_df0.campaign").isNotNull()) & (col("df1.d1_campaignid").isNotNull()), lit('completed')) \
                                  .otherwise("new_df0.d1_action_curated").alias("status")))
```